# How do I create an array from Promise results?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I'm using React to build a web app.  At one point I have a list of ids, and I want to use those to retrieve a list of items from a database, get a list of metrics from each one, and then push those metrics to an array. My code so far is:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const newMetrics = [];

        currentItems.forEach((item) => {

          const url = `items/listmetrics/${item.id}`;

          Client.getData(url).then(async (metrics) => {

            let promises = metrics.map((metricId: string) => {
              // Get metric info
              const urlMetric = `metrics/${metricId}`;
              return Client.getData(urlMetric);
            });
    
            await Promise.all(promises).then((metrics: Array<any>) => {

              metrics.forEach((metric: MetricModel) => {
                  const metricItem = {
                    id: metric.id,
                    metricName: metric.name
                  };
                  newMetrics.push(metricItem);
                }
              });

            });

          });

          setMetrics(newMetrics);
        });

      }, [currentItems]);
```

where "metrics" is a state variable, set by setMetrics.

This appears to work ok, but when I try to access the resulting `metrics` array, it seems to be in the wrong format.  If I try to read the value of `metrics[0]`, it says it's `undefined` (although I know there are several items in `metrics`). Looking at it in the console, `metrics` looks like this:

[image]

However, normally the console shows arrays like this (this is a different variable, I'm just showing how it's listed with `(2) [{...},{...}]`, whereas the one I've created shows as `[]`):

[image]

I'm not confident with using `Promise.all`, so I suspect that that's where I've gone wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: First thing is `await Promise.all(promises).then()` seems odd. You're mixing async/await with the old `then()`  style. Swap to 

`const metrics: Array<any> = await Promise.all(promises)`

Comment: Please show the screenshot content **as text** (also having the image is fine). Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Also I'd normally add an `asyncMap()` library from npm, so you can so `await asyncMap(...)` in a single step. That will do the promise.all bit for you.

Comment: Thanks - I added the p-map npm package, which seems to have resolved it.

Comment: @Sharon, hopefully you are no longer mixing `.then()` and `await` syntaxes.

Comment: Yep, I've sorted that out, thanks!